# Only run function after custom function complete jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I normally do e.g.:

```
$(".item").fadeIn(function(){
    alert('done');
});
```

Which works? (I believe is correct?) but how do I do this with custom functions?

E.g.

```
$(".item").customFunction(function(){
    customFunctionTwo();
});
```

Comment: Call the function at the end of function `function a() { ............ b() }`

Comment: Are you talking about a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Basically it will look like this

```
$.fn.customFunction = function (callback){
    //some code
    callback();
}
$('.item').customFunction(function () {
    customFunctionTwo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be looking at promises https://api.jquery.com/promise/

```
$.fn.customFunction = function (callback){
    var myFn = function(){
        /* your code along with settimeout as well if you choose*/
        //example
        return $( "div" ).fadeIn( 800 ).delay( 1200 ).fadeOut();
    }
    $.when( myFn() ).done(function() {
        callback();
    });
}    

$('.item').customFunction(function () {
    customFunctionTwo();
});
```